# How to process multiple forms in a single template in express

Tags: javascript, express

Let's say I have an index.html with 2 tables in it, one table is "Customers", the other is "Items". There are 2 forms, "Add customer" and "Add item" in the same view. Submitting each forms will add a new entry to the respective table, and a new entry in the database, without directing to another view. How should I do this? How can I detect which form is being submitted and deal with it accordingly?

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
   // Add new customer
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
   // Add new item
})
```

Comment: Just create two different actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common approaches you can take:

- Use different URLs (in the action attributes) with different controllers and then issue an HTTP redirect to `/` as the response.
- Add a hidden input to the forms and use the value of that to switch on which behaviour the `/` controller performs.